# Extract TortoiseSVN saved password

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, forgot-password

Is there any way to extract credentials saved by TortoiseSVN?

Answer (score 240, accepted):

Short answer: You can use **[TortoiseSVN Password Decrypter](http://www.leapbeyond.com/ric/TSvnPD/)** to easily display your cached credentials, including passwords.

Long answer: Here's how the tool works.

The credentials are saved in subdirectories of `%APPDATA%\Subversion\auth\`. Listed from [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720523) they are:

- `svn.simple` contains credentials for basic authentication (username/password)
- `svn.ssl.server` contains SSL server certificates
- `svn.username` contains credentials for username-only authentication (no password needed)

The first directory is the one of interest.  It appears to contain files with names that look like GUIDs; one for each repository for which you've saved credentials.

The passwords in these files are encrypted by the [Windows Data Protection API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx).  The tool above uses sample code from [Obviex](http://www.obviex.com/samples/Code.aspx?Source=DpapiCS&Title=Using%20DPAPI&Lang=C%23) to interface with this API and perform decryption.

In order for it to work, you must have access to the same Windows user account you were running under when you checkmarked the "Save authentication" checkbox.  This is because the Windows Data Protection API uses an encryption key that is tied to your Windows account.  If you lose this account (or, I believe, if an administrator resets your password) then you will no longer be able to decrypt the passwords (except *perhaps* by using brute force / a [third party tool](http://dpapick.com)).  Having a new Windows account with the same username/password (or probably even SID's) is not sufficient.

Answer (score 8):

Based on the info below it sounds like you could possible decrypt them locally in some fashion...

**UPDATE:** Definitive answer from TortiseSVN community

> When they're sent over the wire
>   encrypted, they're encrypted using a
>   handshake and/or agreed-upon key at
>   the time of connection.
>
> When they're stored/read locally,
>   they're encrypted/decrypted via the
>   Windows Crypto API which uses a key
>   tied to your Windows account.
>
> The locally-encrypted copy can't be
>   decrypted by the server because the
>   keys are local to your account.
>
> So when you connect (let's say via
>   HTTPS), your client gets the
>   credentials decrypted via the
>   appropriate Windows API, then includes
>   them in the HTTPS transmission. HTTPS
>   encrypts the *whole* communication
>   between client & server using SSL
>   certificates, not just the
>   credentials.

Comment: are you sure that the password is not decrypted at the client end?

Comment: Pretty certain...without posting an explicit question to the TortiseSVN folks, here is what I found...http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug.html#tsvn-dug-general-auth In addition if it was decrypted client side, then pushed over in plain text to the server it would defeat the purpose. I guess you could send it over via SSH.

Comment: but then effectively anyone could send the ciphertext to the server and tortoiseSVN does not provide any additional security by encryption.

Comment: True which is why they make it known to delete the auth data from your PC on shutdown or at least in a periodic fashion if that is a concern. If the machine holding the auth data has been compromised then that is not really a TotoriseSVN issue per se.

Comment: Thanks for the work. I was hoping there is already a tool for that.