# How to recover lost svn password?

Tags: svn

I just finished reading about passwords in "Version Control with Subversion" but could not find the solution for a lost and forgotten password.
Is there a way to recover a lost svn password?

Comment: That depends on (a) how you have the authentication set up on the server, and (b) how much access you actually have to the server.

Comment: Also, is this a hypothetical question or do you actually have a problem where you've forgotten a password?

Comment: We have no svn server yet. I am investigating svn as a replacement for p4v.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract TortoiseSVN saved password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883129/extract-tortoisesvn-saved-password)

Comment: This isn't a dupe of the TortoiseSVN question - this one is for any SVN implementation

Comment: @eyllanesc maybe - i've not used SVN for about 10y

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've probably read, there are [many ways of setting up a Subversion server](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html).

### svnserve

This is the simplest option. Passwords are stored in a plain text file on the server. Recovery is trivial.

### svnserve over SSH

Subversion is not involved in the authentication process, that is delegated to SSH. All SSH "forgotten password" problems can be solved.

### Apache server

Subversion is not involved in the authentication process, that is delegated to Apache. There are many different authentication methods available for Apache, all of which have some kind of recovery process.

Answer (score 4):

For Windows, there is also an app called TortoiseSVN Password Decrypter which can be used to recover a password from the cache of the user's computer. See http://www.leapbeyond.com/ric/TSvnPD/ (unlike the name suggests, it's not just for TortoiseSVN users).

Note that this is not a admin tool, more a utility that a user can run themselves. Don't know if a similar tool exists for *nix.