# SVN get login credential from repo

Tags: svn

How can I get the current login credentials and remote repository address from the local SVN repo?

Client info:

LINUX/UNIX or MAC, svn, version 1.6.16 (r1073529), compiled Jun 13 2011, 15:54:33

**Update:**

from `cat ~/subversion/auth/svn.simple/*`

```
K 8
passtype
V 8
keychain
K 15
svn:realmstring
V 71
<https://repo.address.com> Repo description
K 8
username
V 12
my.username
END
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's possible at all without eavesdropping on SVN's communication with the server. May I ask why you need it?

Comment: We'll need a bit more detail to answer the question: It depends on what SVN client you are running, and what operating system you are on.

Comment: just curious, I have several repos, and I wonder about it's security

Comment: @EdoDodo: added client info, but it would be nice to know possibilities for all client OS variants. Thanks

Comment: @Marek if it's about security, you definitely have to *assume* that it is possible to get the credentials - AFAIK, they are stored in the SVN client's internal keystore in encrypted form, but they have to be sent to the server at *some* point.

Comment: @Pekka, right, but they can be sent in encrypted form, isn't it? or SVN simple auth is in plaintext?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`svn info` will give you remote repository address.

Assuming you're on Linux/Unix using a stock command line client

```
cat ~/.subversion/auth/svn.simple/*
```

will give you login credentials and alike. Passwords there are stored in an encrypted form, but one can easily [crack them open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910965/recover-svn-password-from-local-cache/5919519#5919519) after looking into `svn` sources.

Comment: Thanks, I will get username, address but not password. see Edit 1 in my question, if it can help you provide how to retrieve password

Comment: great, thanks, I always wondered about how is this working ;-)