# How to know what credentials were used for a TortoiseSVN checkout?

Tags: tortoisesvn

I checked out a folder with TortoiseSVN using some credentials. I don't remember what credentials I used. How can I know what credentials I used to check out the folder? I don't want to change the code for that.

Comment: TortoiseSVN Server? TortoiseSVN is a client. While it can work with repos locally, it does not implement any authorization and authentication.

Answer (score 1):

You could try and commit something then view the log to see who is credited with the commit.

Svn Commit

Tortoise-> Show Log

Edit:

I am assuming what you wanted to ask was "I am running tortoise svn and checked out something from an svn server and used some credentials but I can't remember which username I put in. How can I tell which username I put in?"

Comment: yes, your assumption is correct. But I would like to know the user name without checkin the code

Answer (score 1):

TSvnPwd - [TortoiseSVN Password Decrypter](http://www.leapbeyond.com/ric/TSvnPD/) from Leapbeyond Solutions.

Decrypt stored in %APPDATA%Subversion\auth\ credentials: from [Extract TortoiseSVN saved password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883129/extract-tortoisesvn-saved-password) question