# Decrypt SVN authentication data

Tags: c#, svn, encryption, tortoisesvn, sharpsvn

I would like to get the name of a working copy user.

The authentication data is saved in `%appdata%\subversion\auth.`, however it is encrypted.

Is it possible to decrypt it programmatically using c#?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3883129/761095

Comment: @bahrep, This is an old post and most of the provided links there are stale. Anyway, Thanks for the link.

Comment: the most important link there is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx and it's working

Comment: Working copies do not have the user's name "embedded" in them. You might be able to *guess* by looking at the Windows account, but you can't know for certain what the Subversion user account that checked out/worked with that WC is.

Comment: @alroc, Did you see the tool that Lazy Badger suggested? It works quite nice and gives me the authentication data of current machine. What do you mean in 'Working copies do not have the user's name "embedded" in them'?

Comment: You got the Subversion credentials that were cached in the Windows user profile. You did not necessarily get the Subversion user ID that was using that working copy, because that information is not kept in the working copy (excluding locks that might have been acquired).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TortoiseSVN Password Decrypter](http://www.leapbeyond.com/ric/TSvnPD/) and it's [sources](http://www.leapbeyond.com/ric/TSvnPD/TSvnPwd_source.zip)

Comment: I cannot open the links! Do they corrupt?

Comment: @Lazy Badger, Did you open it?

Comment: @user3165438 - yes, I can see page, DL sources and see C# project inside

Comment: @LazyBadger, how can you show it to me not by this link? Any ideas?