# Local subversion repository accessible in TortoiseSVN, forgot password, password storage location empty ? How to retrieve the data?

Tags: svn, passwords

Strange thing....
I forgot my Subversion password, but can still access the Repository (browsing) via my IDE (Intellij) and TortoiseSVN 1.7.12. TSvnPwd has been used, but could not find anything, so I explored the supposed save location
under C:/<user>/AppData/Roaming/Subversion/auth which contains only directories (svn.simple, svn.ssl*) which are empty, the only exception is a file under svn.username.The .svn directory is empty, too, so both hints from
[this link retrieving it the standard way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883129/extract-tortoisesvn-saved-password?lq=1) are not working.

I am quite perplexed now, I wanted to migrate to Git, but without the password I am at a loss. Is there a default password or something similar ? Is there a way to retrieve my complete repository if I can access it with Tortoise  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local (really local) Subversion repository, accesses using `file:///` protocol doesn't have and can't have any ACL's restriction - it's fully 
anonymous

`.svn` directory doesn't correlate with repository per se - it's part of Working Copy of (any) repository, contain pristine copy of files in Working Copy and doesn't store any authorisation's credentials